$G$-module structure of augmentation ideal
I'm given the following:
Suppose $G$ is a group and let $I$ be the kernel of the homomorphism
$$\mathbb{Z}[G]\to\mathbb{Z}\quad\sum_{g\in G}a_gg\mapsto\sum_{g\in G}a_g$$ (i) Show that $I$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module on the elements $\epsilon_g=g-1$ and describe its $G$-module structure in terms of the action on the $\epsilon_g$.
I've got the first part of the question but I'm not sure how to describe the $G$-module structure in terms of the action on the $\epsilon_g$.
What even is a $G$-module? We usually consider $R$-modules where $R$ is a ring.
Can someone explicitly describe this action?
Thank you.

$G$-module is another name for $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module (equivalently, it's an abelian group with a (left) action by $G$ that's compatible with the group structure).

@BenSteffan By compatible with group structure, you mean $g\cdot(a+b)=g\cdot a+g\cdot b$, correct? Well, what is it? It could be multiplication, it can send every element to the identity, or it can send every element to itself and it's still compatible with the group structure.

For the first question: yes, exactly. For the second question: $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ is a $G$-module; the module structure is given by $\mathbb{Z}[G] \overset{\mathrm{id}}{\to} \mathbb{Z}[G]$. You $I$ is then a submodule of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$, and inherits a $G$-module structure. This is what you're supposed to describe (although I'm not quite sure what's meant by "describe" here).

@BenSteffan So $\mathbb{Z}[G]\times\mathbb{Z}[G]\to\mathbb{Z}[G]$, or $G\times\mathbb{Z}[G]\to\mathbb{Z}[G]$? This is still confusing me. Can you take an element of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ and apply the action explicitly? Sorry if this seems trivial.

Forget about group actions for a second. A $G$-module is a module over the ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$. Obviously $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ is a module over itself; and the module multiplication is just the multiplication of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ as a ring (for instance, if $g \in G$ is any element you have $g \cdot (1 + 2 g^2 - 17 g^{-1}) = g + 2 g^3 - 17$, and so on). Try and work it out on this level, and when you're done try proving that the descriptions of $G$-modules as modules over $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ and as abelian groups with group actions are equivalent :)
